# multiple ssh windows & keep positions

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

Is there an app to would allow me to save & restore multiple SSH windows on Ubuntu?

I use many ssh session windows and I would like to be able to save the screen position of every one of them & be able to restore those.

Comment: Have you tried e.g. [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: I don't particularly like tmux: I was hoping was something more user friendly.

Comment: Then list what you have tried and don't like so people know what you want instead of them suggesting things that you already tried. Also, the term "user friendly" is not very well defined (it's easy to argue that tmux is _very_ "user friendly"), so you need to elaborate more if you want suggestions that fit you.

Comment: Good suggestion:  I've tried Tmux, screen and omnity (but couldn't figure it out).  By "user friendly" I mean the capability to use the mouse to perform some basic actions like "pane selection".

Comment: What about Guake?  Have you looked at that?

Answer (score 0):

There is a "restore running apps" setting that can be turned on somewhere in the control panel. Once that is enabled, just leave your windows/sessions open when you shutdown (you can still log out of the apps, but don't close the window), and they should auto-open when you restart.